# Dynamically create/delete drawn objects on tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have managed to dynamically create various rectangles on the tkinter canvas widget using the below code:

```
setattr(self, "wall_" + str(counter), self.canvas_base.create_rectangle(*sel_wall,fill="black"))
```

Where `counter` is an increasing and variable integer, `canvas_base` is the canvas being drawn on, `suffix` is a string alternating between `a` and `b`, and `sel_wall` is a list of coordinates used to draw the rectangle.

Is there a way to dynamically delete these objects on the canvas (varying from `wall_1` to something like `wall_5`), or is there a better alternative combination to create/delete these canvas objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to deal with an arbitrary number of similar objects, the proper solution is to put them in a list (or other container object).  You can easily iterate over the list to do something to all the objects, such as deleting them.